# How to insert a line in a text file at a designated spot using sed+regex?

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I have a text file similar to the example below.

I want to insert

```
<string>insert-me</string>
```

at the indicated line.

How can I do it? I tried variations similar to this:

```
sed "/s/<key>first</key>/\n        <array>/\n/test/g" test.txt
```

and I keep on getting "bad flag in substitute command" error.

Thanks

**sample text file:**

```
<record>
    <key>first</key>
    <array>
        --I want to insert the line here--
        <string>hello</string>
        <string>world</string>
        </array>
</record>
<record>
    <key>second</key>
    <array>
        <string>its</string>
        <string>me</string>
        <string>again</string>
        <string>hello</string>
        <string>world</string>
        <string>again</string>
    </array>
</record>
```

Comment: Your question does not match the sample text. Do you want to change the first (acc. sample text) or the second record (acc. question)?

Comment: post the expected result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several issues here (beyond the general one of trying to parse structured data with regex tools)

1. if your pattern (or replacement) contains slashes, then you either need to use a different separator for the sed commands, or escape the slashes
2. sed is (normally) line-oriented, so you can't match across line boundaries unless you pull additional lines into the pattern space with `N`
3. matching specific amounts of whitespace is going to make the whole thing even more fragile

So for example you could do:

```
sed '/<key>second<\/key>/ {N; s/\n[[:blank:]]*<array>/&\n\tinsert-me/;}' test.txt
```

or (more naturally) using **a**ppend rather than **s**ubstitute

```
sed -e '/<key>second<\/key>/ {N; /<array>/ a\\tinsert-me' -e ';}' test.txt
<record>
    <key>first</key>
    <array>
        --I want to insert the line here--
        <string>hello</string>
        <string>world</string>
        </array>
</record>
<record>
    <key>second</key>
    <array>
        insert-me
        <string>its</string>
        <string>me</string>
        <string>again</string>
        <string>hello</string>
        <string>world</string>
        <string>again</string>
    </array>
</record>
```